# javac doesn't match annotation processor

Tags: annotations, javac, java-8, annotation-processing

I have an artifact contains an annotation and an annotation processor for that.

With JDK 7, `javac` properly matches and process the processor.

```
Round 1:
        input files: {HelloWorldTest}
        annotations: [HelloWorldProcessor]
        last round: false
...
Round 2:
        input files: {}
        annotations: []
        last round: true
```

With JDK 8, `javac` simply doesn't.

```
Round 1:
        input files: {HelloWorldTest}
        annotations: []
        last round: false
...
Round 2:
        input files: {}
        annotations: []
        last round: true
```

The library artifact compiles for -target 1.7.
What possibly did I do wrong? Is there any reported bug with JDK8's javac?

Here is my Annotation class.

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface HelloWorldBuffer {
    // ...
}
```

I'm quite sure that the Annotation, the Processor, and the `META-INF/services/...` settings correct.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?